# sql last recorded row take too long too query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using the following query to get the last row of the table. This code seems to be what should be done for this type of query. So I am wondering why it takes so long for the table to output the result.
I am looking for the potential reasons that could lead to this long time to query. For example maybe the row is not in the top (I use some conditions) and it takes time to reach the row if the query read from top to bottom of the table? Or the query need to read all the table before to conclude which row is correct (I don't think it is the case)?

Any contribution to know how the "sorting algo" is working is appreciated.

The code:

```
SELECT created_at , currency, balance 
from YYY
where id in (ZZZ) and currency = 'XXX'
order by created_at desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: How many rows are in the table? How many different currencies? How many rows (min/max) for one currency? How many IDs are in your IN clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select created_at, currency, balance 
from YYY
where id in (ZZZ) and currency = 'XXX'
order by created_at desc
limit 1;
```

If your query has no indexes, then the engine needs to scan the entire table, choose the rows that match the `where` clause, sort those rows and choose the one with the maximum `created_at`.

If you have an index on `YYY(currency, id, created_at desc)`, then the engine can simply look up the appropriate value right away using the index.

So, if you have the right optimizations in the database, then the query is likely to be much, much faster.

Comment: Thank you that is the answer I was looking for